# How do I queue QProcesses in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qprocess

I want to queue QProcess in PyQt5 or simply block while still reading the stdout with readAll(). The equivalent of subprocess.call instead of subprocess.Pop. When using waitForFinished() the stdout with readAll() will all come at once when the process is ended instead of flowing out while it's processing.

Example script:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui,QtCore, QtWidgets

class gui(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(gui, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def dataReady(self):
        cursor = self.output.textCursor()
        cursor.movePosition(cursor.End)
        cursor.insertText(str(self.process.readAll(), "utf-8"))
        self.output.ensureCursorVisible()


    def callProgram(self):
        # run the process
        # `start` takes the exec and a list of argument

        filepath = 'path\image.tif'

        self.process.start('some_command filepath'])

        # This will output a file image.tif specified by filepath: 

        # Import file and do stuff to it:

        # E.g.

        im = Image.open('filepath')

        imarray = np.array(im)

        # Get image extents as argument to next process:

        ext = str(imarray.size)


        imarray[imarray == 10] = 5

        # Save changes

        im = Image.fromarray(imarray)
        im.save(filepath)            

        # Now the image has been updated and should be in a new process below

        cmd = 'some_other_command' + filepath + ext

        self.process.start(cmd)

        # Same thing goes on here:

        self.process.start('some_command filepath')

        # Import file once again

        im = Image.open('filepath')

        imarray[imarray == 10] = 5

        # Save changes

        im = Image.fromarray(imarray)
        im.save(filepath)    

    def initUI(self):

        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.runButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Run')
        self.runButton.clicked.connect(self.callProgram)

        self.output = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()

        layout.addWidget(self.output)
        layout.addWidget(self.runButton)

        centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        centralWidget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        # QProcess object for external app
        self.process = QtCore.QProcess(self)
        # QProcess emits `readyRead` when there is data to be read
        self.process.readyRead.connect(self.dataReady)

        # Just to prevent accidentally running multiple times
        # Disable the button when process starts, and enable it when it finishes
        self.process.started.connect(lambda: self.runButton.setEnabled(False))
        self.process.finished.connect(lambda: self.runButton.setEnabled(True))


#Function Main Start
def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui=gui()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
#Function Main END

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: @eyllanesc task n to be executed after task n-1. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @eyllanesc E.g. if I run self.process.start('ping',['127.0.0.1']), it will output print statements in stdout real time if I readAll(). Such processes I would like to do so that they are as such: task n to be executed after task n-1. However, while they still output to stdout in real time, which I couldn't get to work with waitForFinished() as the whole output would be printed after each of the processes were done.

Comment: @eyllanesc The reason for this is that was I call with QProcess outputs increments for a loading bar. If all these increments are printed only when the process is done when using waitForFinished() it ruins the purpose of the loading bar. I have multiple calls after each other using QProcess and they cannot be run in parallel as the output file is used in the other.

Comment: @eyllanesc In my original script I have many subprocess.call() after each other where each outputs a file needed in the next (which is why I can't use subprocess.Popen()). This I would like to transfer to QProcess as I want to make use of the real time print statements for a loading bar in my UI.

Comment: @eyllanesc Done.

Comment: @eyllanesc Actually, the first process outputs a file used in the next two, where one of these output a file used in a next one again, while the other should be imported in the script as an array.  But if such control is too much of a hassle or simply not possible. Then this will satisfy: process output of n going to be the input of process n + 1. However, still while reading the print statements real time of the processes.

Comment: @eyllanesc Many thanks for the help! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution in this case is to create a `TaskManager` class that is responsible for handling the sequentiality between the tasks.

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from functools import partial

class TaskManager(QtCore.QObject):
    started = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    finished = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    progressChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int, QtCore.QByteArray)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtCore.QObject.__init__(self, parent)
        self._process = QtCore.QProcess(self)
        self._process.finished.connect(self.handleFinished)
        self._progress = 0

    def start_tasks(self, tasks):
        self._tasks = iter(tasks)
        self.fetchNext()
        self.started.emit()
        self._progress = 0

    def fetchNext(self):
            try:
                task = next(self._tasks)
            except StopIteration:
                return False
            else:
                self._process.start(*task)
            return True

    def processCurrentTask(self):
        output = self._process.readAllStandardOutput()
        self._progress += 1
        self.progressChanged.emit(self._progress, output)

    def handleFinished(self):
        self.processCurrentTask()
        if not self.fetchNext():
            self.finished.emit()



class gui(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(gui, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()


    def dataReady(self, progress, result):
        self.output.append(str(result, "utf-8"))
        self.progressBar.setValue(progress)

    def callProgram(self):
        tasks = [("ping", ["8.8.8.8"]),
                 ("ping", ["8.8.8.8"]),
                 ("ping", ["8.8.8.8"])]

        self.progressBar.setMaximum(len(tasks))
        self.manager.start_tasks(tasks)

    def initUI(self):
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.runButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Run')

        self.runButton.clicked.connect(self.callProgram)

        self.output = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()

        self.progressBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar()

        layout.addWidget(self.output)
        layout.addWidget(self.runButton)
        layout.addWidget(self.progressBar)

        centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        centralWidget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        self.manager = TaskManager(self)
        self.manager.progressChanged.connect(self.dataReady)
        self.manager.started.connect(partial(self.runButton.setEnabled, False))
        self.manager.finished.connect(partial(self.runButton.setEnabled, True))


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui=gui()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

Update:

Generalizing the problem, it can be said that the n-th process needs default arguments and additional arguments.

- The default arguments are independent and fixed
- The additional arguments depend on the previous process through a certain function.

So it can be generalized using the following expressions:

```
result_n = process_n(default_arguments, additional_args_n)`
additional_args_n = fun_n(result_n-1)`
```

or using the following diagram:

```
 ________      _________      ________      _________      ________
|        |    |         |    |        |    |         |    |        |
|        |    |         |    |        |    |         |    |        |
| TASK-1 |--->| FUN1TO2 |--->| TASK-2 |--->| FUN2TO3 |--->| TASK-3 |
|        |    |         |    |        |    |         |    |        |
|________|    |_________|    |________|    |_________|    |________|
```

Then to structure the process the following dictionary is created:

```
task_n = {"program": program, "args": default_arguments, "function": fun}
```

Where `fun` is the function used to process the output of this task to obtain additional arguments for the next task.

In the following example, I will use `scriptX.py` as a program instead of `ping`.

```
#script1.py
import sys

def foo(*args):
    v,  = args
    return "1-"+"".join(v)

arg = sys.argv[1:]
print(foo(arg))

#script2.py
import sys

def foo(*args):
    v,  = args
    return "2-"+"".join(v)

arg = sys.argv[1:]
print(foo(arg))

#script3.py
import sys

def foo(*args):
    v,  = args
    return "3-"+"".join(v)

arg = sys.argv[1:]
print(foo(arg))
```

`fun1to2` is the function that uses the result of process-1 to generate the additional argument required by process-2 and must return it. similar case for `fun2to3`

```
def fun1to2(*args):
    return "additional_arg_for_process2_from_result1" 

def fun2to3(*args):
    return "additional_arg_for_process3_from_result2"
```

so based on the above we create the tasks:

```
tasks = [{"program": "python", "args": ["scripts/script1.py", "default_argument1"], "function": fun1to2},
         {"program": "python", "args": ["scripts/script2.py", "default_argument2"], "function": fun2to3},
         {"program": "python", "args": ["scripts/script3.py", "default_argument3"]}]
```

Using all of the above, the final implementation is as follows:

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from functools import partial

class TaskManager(QtCore.QObject):
    started = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    finished = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    progressChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int, QtCore.QByteArray)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtCore.QObject.__init__(self, parent)
        self._process = QtCore.QProcess(self)
        self._process.finished.connect(self.handleFinished)
        self._progress = 0
        self._currentTask = None

    def start_tasks(self, tasks):
        self._tasks = iter(tasks)
        self.fetchNext()
        self.started.emit()
        self._progress = 0

    def fetchNext(self, additional_args=None):
            try:
                self._currentTask = next(self._tasks)
            except StopIteration:
                return False
            else:
                program = self._currentTask.get("program")
                args = self._currentTask.get("args")
                if additional_args is not None:
                    args += additional_args
                self._process.start(program, args)
            return True

    def processCurrentTask(self):
        output = self._process.readAllStandardOutput()
        self._progress += 1
        fun = self._currentTask.get("function")
        res = None
        if fun:
            res = fun(output)
        self.progressChanged.emit(self._progress, output)
        return res

    def handleFinished(self):
        args = self.processCurrentTask()
        if not self.fetchNext(args):
            self.finished.emit()


def fun1to2(args):
    return "-additional_arg_for_process2_from_result1" 

def fun2to3(args):
    return "-additional_arg_for_process3_from_result2" 

class gui(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(gui, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()


    def dataReady(self, progress, result):
        self.output.append(str(result, "utf-8"))
        self.progressBar.setValue(progress)


    def callProgram(self):
        tasks = [{"program": "python", "args": ["scripts/script1.py", "default_argument1"], "function": fun1to2},
                 {"program": "python", "args": ["scripts/script2.py", "default_argument2"], "function": fun2to3},
                 {"program": "python", "args": ["scripts/script3.py", "default_argument3"]}]

        self.progressBar.setMaximum(len(tasks))
        self.manager.start_tasks(tasks)

    def initUI(self):
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.runButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Run')

        self.runButton.clicked.connect(self.callProgram)

        self.output = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()

        self.progressBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar()

        layout.addWidget(self.output)
        layout.addWidget(self.runButton)
        layout.addWidget(self.progressBar)

        centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        centralWidget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        self.manager = TaskManager(self)
        self.manager.progressChanged.connect(self.dataReady)
        self.manager.started.connect(partial(self.runButton.setEnabled, False))
        self.manager.finished.connect(partial(self.runButton.setEnabled, True))


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui=gui()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works as intended! However, if let's say the first task output a file which I wanted to import and do stuff to before initiating the next task. Is that possible?

Comment: The first process outputs a file, which I import as an array and do changes to. Then I save that array as a file and use that file in the next process.

Comment: Tried to update again! Sorry for the misunderstanding!  And yes you're exactly right: Do you want the n-th process to take as arguments some data that depends on the output of the (n-1)-th process?

Comment: I wish it to be exactly as you said: the nth process take as arguments some data that depends on the output of the (n-1)-th process!

Comment: Yes I can see the confusion arising from that! My bad!

Comment: Code inbetween the QProcess calls are indeed fast.

Comment: They do depend on im! Editing script again. I forgot to add this part.

Comment: Did the final edits! This is it :) Sorry for dragging you along this tedious path.

Comment: Thanks! Just what I needed. I appreciate your elaborate answer!

Comment: Where would we add `self._process.waitForStarted()` and or `self._process.waitForFinished()` (or similar?) in the grand scheme of things, should we need to give one process sometime to execute or even finish completely, before the next one is triggered?

Comment: @Natetronn do not use the waitX methods since they are blocking, in this case you must use signals

Comment: @eyllanesc thanks for the reply! Any chance you'd be willing to add an example for that? Or would it be best to create another question at this point, based on this one?

Comment: @Natetronn in my answer is the n-th finished qprocess signal to start the (n + 1) qprocess. What do you not understand from my answer?

Comment: @eyllanesc yes, it makes sense now. I programmatically slowed down script2.py and now I see it's doing exactly what you said. It's very well thought out and super helpful. Thank you for the amazing answer and for the replies too!